# java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath

Tags: code-coverage, junit4, jmockit

I am getting below exception when i am trying to runing the Junit testcases.
If i am changing the classpath entry order it is working fine but the Jococo coverage is not working.It is getting hanging. 
Can any please help to fix this issue.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libt/junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jmockit.jar"/>
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath (if using JUnit; if not, check the documentation)
    at com.amica.bc.testutil.BillingCenterTestUtil$1.<init>(BillingCenterTestUtil.java:18)
at com.amica.bc.testutil.BillingCenterTestUtil.setCurrentUserName(BillingCenterTestUtil.java:18)
    at amica.util.logging.TestAmicaGWLogger.setUp(TestAmicaGWLogger.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 5):

SYMPTOM:
Error when run maven with Jmockit and junit into java project.

MESSAGE:
JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath (if using JUnit; if not, check the documentation)

CAUSES:

Wrong configured in POM.xml file. Jmockit dependencyis is after of junit.

SOLUTIONS:

Edit POM.xml file. The jmockit.jar should be precedes junit.jar then jmockit dependency should be before of junit.

Comment: Also make sure that you do not have JUnit library included in your build path. I had JUnit lib included in my build path and both JUnit and JMockit dependencies (JMockit preceding JUnit) in my pom.xml. Removing extra JUnit lib from build path solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

The official guide tells us the following:

> JMockit also requires the -javaagent JVM initialization parameter to
>   be used; when using the Maven Surefire plugin for test execution, it's
>   specified as follows:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.21.0</version> <!-- or some other version -->
      <configuration>
         <argLine>
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
         </argLine>
         <!-- ... -->
      </configuration>
   <plugin>
   <!-- ... -->
<plugins>
```

More details [here](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html) and [here](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#maven).

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem while running my standalone application which requires both jars **junit-4.8.1.jar** and **jmockit-0.999.4.jar**. Below are the steps, I did to make this work :

**1.** Go to pom.xml. Click on **depdendency hierarchy** option and type "junit" in search bar. From here you will get to know from which dependency your "junit" is coming. Here I found that "nature-6.51" depdendency was responsible for that in my project (Note it down whatever is urs).

[image: junit dependency]

**2.** Type "jmockit" in search bar and note down the dependency showing here (jmockit-0.999.4)

[image: jmockit dependency]

**3.** Go to pom.xml and search for "nature" *(or dependency responsible for junit)* and "jmockit" dependency we have noted down in step #1 and #2 respectively. You will see that ***nature*** dependency will be listed above ***jmockit*** dependency.

**4.** Now just copy the *jmockit dependency* and place it just above the *nature-6.51* dependency (which I did bcz nature's jar was carrying junit in my project)

This worked for me successfully. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that a test was defined in the `main` source folder, instead of the `test` source folder. The dependencies for jmockit and junit we defined in the pom with scope test. Therefore they were not available for this test.

The IDE wasn't that strict during editting and compilation, so no warnings whatsoever, but the tests failed with this same strange error.

Comment: All mocking tools that modify the classes under test have the same problem with JaCoCo. We're successfully using Mockito for mocking in combination with JaCoCo. This works as long as you don't use the spy() functionality to intercept the class under test.